# Android my notification doesn't pop up on wearable device

Tags: android, notifications

My app's notification doens't pop-up on my android wearable watch.

As far as I know I don't need to do something for notification to be shown on android wearable device. Is it right?

Other app's notification pops up perfectly.
Interesting thing is that after closing other app's notification, my app's notification is shown to the front!

Another symtom: wearable extended action is applied to non-wearable device.

> ```
> import android.app.Notification;
> import android.app.PendingIntent;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.os.Build;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
> import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
> import android.support.v4.app.RemoteInput;
> import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.view.View;
>
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
>     private static final String REPLY_ACTION = "342123";
>     private static final String EXIT_ACTION = "6454";
>     private static final String KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID = "1331133131";
>     private static final String KEY_MESSAGE_ID = "213213";
>     int NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE = 11;
>     String KEY_REPLY = "2323123";
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>         Log.d("haha", "");
>     }
>
>     public void onButtonClick(View view) {
>         sendNotification();
>     }
>
>     public void sendNotification() {
>
>         NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
>
>         NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHA");
>         builder
>                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
>                 .setContentTitle("Title")
>                 .setShowWhen(true)
>                 .extend(createWearableExtender())
>                 .addAction(createReplyAction())
>                 .addAction(createExitAction())
>                 .setContentText("assdsdsdsda");
>
>         managerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE, builder.build());
>     }
>
>     private NotificationCompat.WearableExtender createWearableExtender() {
>         NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender();
>         wearableExtender.addAction(createReplyAction());
>         wearableExtender.addAction(createExitAction());
>         wearableExtender.addPage(new Notification());
>         return wearableExtender;
>     }
>
>     private NotificationCompat.Action createReplyAction() {
>         PendingIntent pendingIntent;
>         Intent intent;
>         RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_REPLY)
>                 .setLabel("Reply Label 2")
>                 .build();
>
>         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
>             // start a
>             // (i)  broadcast receiver which runs on the UI thread or
>             // (ii) service for a background task to b executed , but for the purpose of
>             // this codelab, will be doing a broadcast receiver
>             intent = new Intent(this, NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
>             intent.setAction(REPLY_ACTION);
>             intent.putExtra(KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE);
>             intent.putExtra(KEY_MESSAGE_ID, KEY_REPLY);
>             pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent,
>                     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>         } else {
>             // start your activity for Android M and below
>             intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
>             intent.setAction(REPLY_ACTION);
>             intent.putExtra(KEY_MESSAGE_ID, KEY_REPLY);
>             intent.putExtra(KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE);
>             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
>             pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 100, intent,
>                     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>         }
>
>         return new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
>                 R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Reply Label", pendingIntent)
>                 .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
>                 .build();
>     }
>
>
>     private NotificationCompat.Action createExitAction() {
>         Intent intent;
>         PendingIntent pendingIntent;
>         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
>             intent = new Intent(this, NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
>             intent.setAction(EXIT_ACTION);
>             intent.putExtra(KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE);
>             intent.putExtra(KEY_MESSAGE_ID, KEY_REPLY);
>             pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent,
>                     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>         } else {
>             // start your activity for Android M and below
>             intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
>             intent.setAction(EXIT_ACTION);
>             intent.putExtra(KEY_MESSAGE_ID, KEY_REPLY);
>             intent.putExtra(KEY_NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE);
>             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
>             pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 100, intent,
>                     PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>         }
>
>         return new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
>                 R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "Exit", pendingIntent)
>                 .build();
>     }
> }
> ```

Manifest.xml looks like this:

> ```
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <receiver
>         android:name=".NotificationBroadcastReceiver"
>         android:enabled="true"
>         android:exported="false" />
>
> </application> </manifest>
> ```